# What is the default TLS version in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.server) the default value for `server.ssl.protocol` is `TLS`, but it does not specify which version will be used.

I read that TLS 1.3 is available since java 11 but is it used by default in Sprint boot when available?

Is there any configuration that can tell me which version is used in my project?
Or any documentation depending on the Spring boot version that could tell the TLS version used by the framework?

Answer (score 2):

I am using **Spring Boot 2.7.3** and **JDK 17** and by default, it supports **TLSv1.3**

You can check that by running the below command. My application is running locally on port 8080 so I passed `127.0.01:8080` after `-connect`

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.01:8080
```

**Output**

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140704377439424:error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/810eba08-405a-11ed-86e9-6af958a02716/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_lib.c:151:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 294 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Start Time: 1668006818
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

You can change the TLS version by this property.

`server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2`

Want to read more about this? refer below links

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.configure-ssl

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.server.server.ssl.enabled-protocols